# How to define an operator with an index argument below?

Tags: math-operators, subscripts

I am defining a trace symbol as follows:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}
```

but now I would like to be able to insert a summation variable below. However `\Tr_x` places the subscript `x` on the side:

[image]

I want the subscript below, like this:

[image]

I know I can achieve this by typing `\underset{x}{\Tr}`, but that's a long command. Is there a way to have the subscript placed below by default whenever I use `\Tr`? Or another way of defining the operator/command that achieves this easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get behavior like with `\lim` use the starred version

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Tr}{Tr}
```

Remember `typeset under` is only seen in display math, in text style math it is still written on the side as it should or it would disturb line distance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Tr}{Tr}
\begin{document}
$\Tr_x(b)$

\[
\Tr_x(b)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]